# How can I dynamically change the size of groupBox when I add new controls in it?

Tags: c#, .net, groupbox

Hi my problem is:I create GroupBoxs dynamically and I add into the groupboxs a number of controls in (my case radioButtons ) I'd like the groupboxs to size dynaically in order to display all the RadioButtons that I insert into them. How can I do?
This is the code:

```
 private void IdEnForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].Count; j++)
            {
                bool help;
                if (j == 0) help = true;
                else help = false;


                if (help)
                {

                    gb = new GroupBox();
                    gb.Text = " which Entity you want to mantain?";
                    gb.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);
                    gb.AutoSize = true;
                    gb.Location = new Point(j * 150, (i + 1) * 100);


                }                      
                RadioButton  rb = new RadioButton();
                rb.Text=""+  a[i][j];
                rb.AutoSize = true;
                gb.Controls.Add(rb);

                this.Controls.Add(gb);

               // MessageBox.Show("" + a[i][j]);

            }
enter code here
```

Comment: Which UI framework are you using? WinForms, WebForms, WPF, Silverlight? (You have "Form" in your method name, so it's probably either WinForms or WebForms.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an Event Handler to trigger When a Control is added to the groupbox like this:

```
groupbox.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler( groupbox_ControlAdded );
```

And then add a method to deal with the event:

```
void groupbox_ControlAdded( object sender, ControlEventArgs e )
    {
        //Do Resizing here
    }
```